Не могу получить и отправить статистику на Steamworks
Не могу получить статистику со Steamworks и не могу ее засетить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?
int value2 = 21;
bool successSet2 = Steamworks.SteamUserStats.SetStat("PlayerLevel", value2);
Debug.Log($"SetStat success: {successSet2}, value: {value2}");        
if (successSet2)
{
    bool storeSuccess = SteamUserStats.StoreStats();
    Debug.Log($"StoreStats success: {storeSuccess}");
}        
int numPlayerLvl;
bool success3 = Steamworks.SteamUserStats.GetStat("PlayerLevel", out numPlayerLvl);
Debug.Log($"GetStat success: {success3}, PlayerLevel: {numPlayerLvl}");        
if (success3)
{
    Debug.Log("Successfully retrieved PlayerLevel.");
}      
SetStat success: False, value: 21
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
PuzzleKing.Components.Steam.SteamTest:Start () (at Assets/_Components/Steam/SteamTest.cs:94)


не могу получить статистику со стимворкс и не могу ее засетить.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить єту проблему?
